# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am attempting to upgrade CKEditor from 4.5.10 to 4.6.2, but am getting the following error in the Chrome console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined

[Image of error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLocW.png)

Any ideas at what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a caching issue; try clearing your browser cache and see if that resolves your issue.

I'm having the same issue, and so far all the research I've done points towards a cache issue (although I haven't solved it for me, despite clearing my cache).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue was, but I am assuming it had to do with plugins. I redownloaded CKEditor, and was able to get it going.